# Upload Multiple Images to API using Multi Image Picker

Tags: flutter, dart, upload, photo

I am attempting to implement the ability to upload multiple images (along with some other data) to an API using data entered via a form on my flutter application.

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker which stores all the images as a `List<Asset>`

The API I am attempting to connect with says it requires the following fields.

```
firstname, lastname and images[].
```

I have started to encode the json body using:

```
var body = json.encode({"firstname": firstNameField, "lastname": lastNameField, "images": imageList});
```

but this failed. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What error message are you seeing? Consider reading this article about [serialization in flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hey @Bollie, You can do using the [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader) package, it's very simple you can post your data in formdata separately with multiple files/images.
here is more info on how you can do,Hope it'll work for you..**   https://github.com/BlueChilli/flutter_uploader/issues/9

- *feel free to ask any questions regarding this, Actually I recently did it so...*